# How to start sigmoid from origin?

Tags: python, graph, sigmoid

[Desired graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxqCO.png)

There are several different implementations of sigmoid function in Python, but all of them started from negative x coordinate axis. But how to start it from x=0?

Comment: You'll need to fiddle with the offset. Here's a [desmos calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5up6hhzsmg) where you can play around with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a maths question than a Python question. The problem is that a sigmoid function never actually "reaches" zero (assuming you are moving along it in the negative direction). This is called an [asymptotic function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Asymptotic.html).

However, you can move the centre of the sigmoid by adding or subtracting from its argument. E.g. sigmoid(x-1) will move the centre of the sigmoid to +1 on the x axis. Where exactly you decide to move it to depends on your application, because of the reason I explained previously. In some disciplines this may be 2% or 5%, but it depends what you need it for.